# First page of CV not visible in the output of my LaTeX document

Tags: errors, cv

For some reason, the first page of my CV created with LaTeX is not visible. I can only see the text starting from "Extracurricular Activities". Could someone please tell me what is wrong with the code? I'd be really happy to know! Here is the code (I removed personal details about myself and changed it to 0s):

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section
\usepackage{xcolor}

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}
%%%

%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%no pagebreak
\newenvironment{absolutelynopagebreak}
  {\par\nobreak\vfil\penalty0\vfilneg
   \vtop\bgroup}
  {\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
   \prevdepth=\tpd}

%artikel citen   
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Imports bibliography file   
   
%start firstpage
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\begin{absolutelynopagebreak}

%WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
%\font\wm=''Baskerville:color=787878'' at 8pt
%\font\wmweb=''Baskerville:color=FF1493'' at 8pt
%{\wm 
%   \begin{textblock}{1}(0,0)
%       \rotatebox{-90}{\parbox{500mm}{
%           Typeset by Alessandro Plasmati with \XeTeX\  \today\ for 
%           {\wmweb \href{http://www.aleplasmati.comuv.com}{aleplasmati.comuv.com}}
%       }
%   }
%   \end{textblock}
%}



\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\par{\centering
        {\Huge 0 \textsc{0
    }\bigskip\par}}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------

%Section: Personal Data
\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & 0  | 0 \\
    \textsc{Address:}   &  0 \\
    \textsc{Phone:}     & 0\\
    \textsc{email:}     & \href{0}{0}
\end{tabular}

%Section: Education
\section{Education}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
 \textsc{Sep 2020} &  0 (0) \\ & \emph{0} \\&\footnotesize{0.}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
 \textsc{Sep 2019 - Sep 2020} & 0 (0}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
 \textsc{Sep 2016 - Sep 2019} & 0 (0) \\&\emph{0}\\&\footnotesize{0}  \\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\textsc{Sep 2009 - Jun 2015} & 0
\textsc{0} \\&\emph{0}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\\end{tabular}

\thispagestyle{empty}
%Section: Work Experience at the top
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\textsc{Mar 2019 - Jul 2019} & 0
\\\textsc{ }&\emph{0} \\&\footnotesize{0.}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}
\\\textsc{Jan 2016 - Apr 2016} & 0\\&\footnotesize{0.}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{Nov 2015 - Apr 2019} & 0\\&\footnotesize{0}\\\end{tabular}\thispagestyle{empty}\end{absolutelynopagebreak}

%Section: Extracurricular activities
\section{Extracurricular Activities}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
 \textsc{Nov 2020} & 0\\&\emph{0}\\&\footnotesize{0}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
  \textsc{Jan 2014 - Nov 2020} & 0\\&\emph{0}\\&\footnotesize{0.}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
 \textsc{Sep 2018 - Sep 2019} & 0 \\&\emph{0}\\&\footnotesize{0}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
 \textsc{Sep 2018 - Sep 2019} & 0 \\&\emph{0}\\&\footnotesize{0.}
\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{Dec 2017 - Mar 2018} & 0\\&\emph{0}\\&\footnotesize{0}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{Oct 2015 - Jan 2016} & 0\\&\emph{0}\\&\footnotesize{0.}
\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{Sep 2011 - Jul 2012} & 0\textsc{0}, \\&\emph{0}\\&\footnotesize{0.} 
\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}

%Section: Languages
\section{Languages}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
 \textsc{0:}&0\\
\textsc{0:}&0\\
\textsc{0:}&0\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Interests and Activities}
0.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}` supposed to do? Doesn't this remove the first page?

Comment: It seems you have two different accounts on the site (this one and the one from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578728/specific-question-about-deleting-text-in-latex-leading-to-distorted-output). If you want you can have the two accounts merged by clicking `Flag`-`in need of moderator intervention` below one of the posts.

Comment: Thank you so much leandriis! That was indeed the error.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...